# Apply mask/material by angle of an face

Tags: texturing, masking

Is there a way to apply a map, mask, or material by an angle threshold? I have done this in C4D years ago but unfortunately no reference to share.

For example, on a mountain, I want to apply snow on parts that are flatter while on steeper parts I want to apply the mountain texture.

Thanks,
Stefan

Quick test and result after I got the answer and exactly what I wanted!:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *Input > Geometry* node, plug its *Normal* output socket into a *Converter > Separate XYZ* node in order to determine the angle. You can also plug a *Mapping* node between the *Geometry* and the *Separate XYZ* if you want to tilt the angle:

[image]

Use a b&w *ColorRamp* if you want to use the *Geometry* node as a factor between two textures:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could take the dot-product of the normal of the surface with the unit Z vector, as a measure of the angle with Z.

It's `cos`(the angle with Z), if you want to `arccos` it, for the actual angle, in radians.

[image]